# How to enable bluetooth when there is no hardware switch

Tags: unity, bluetooth, thinkpad

My laptop Thinkpad Edge e320 got out of standby with bluetooth and wireless disabled. WiFi got enabled normally in unity but bluetooth says that "bluetooth is disabled by hardware switch".

There is no hw switch on my laptop. I tried:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/bluetooth_enable 
bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

but as you see no results.

Fn-F9, which is radio control, does not work. Any help?

Comment: Do you have root account enabled ?

Comment: yes, '#' indicates that it is executed as root

Comment: Do check this answer when you got time -- [How to enable hard-blocked bluetooth in Thinkpad Edge 320](http://askubuntu.com/a/513380)