# How to enable hard-blocked bluetooth in Thinkpad Edge 320

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, lenovo, thinkpad, acpi

I'm trying to use the built-in bluetooth device of my Lenovo Thinkpad E320.
It seems to be hard blocked, but i can't find any possibility to unblock it.

`rfkill list` returns:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth   
Soft blocked: yes   
Hard blocked:yes
```

`cat /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth` returns:

```
status:     disabled
commands:   enable, disable
```

I tried to enable it by:

- Pressing Fn+F9 (Radio controll)
- `echo enable | tee /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth`
- `rfkill unblock bluetooth`
- Trough the BIOS. But it's not mentioned at all

None of the actions influenced the ouputs above.

Comment: I believe you've left off the quotes around `enable` in `echo enable | tee /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth`. It should be `echo 'enable' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/bluetooth` IIRC,

Comment: Still no success... (with quotes)

Comment: Some people activated bluetooth in a dual booted windows. After a reboot it worked in linux too.

Comment: I have the same issues and can temporarily get it working disabling the bios settings related to Bluetooth, restarting and then re-enabling them again. However unfortunately this reverts back as soon as I suspend the laptop and then I have to repeat the whole process over again. Not really what I'd expect from an Ubuntu certified laptop. :-/

Answer (score 5):

after 5-10 bios resets to re-enable bluetooth during the last two years I decided to investigate this issue again. looks like there is a bluetooth switch emulation in the thinkpad_acpi module. turn this on via module options et voila -> working bluetooth!

```
echo options thinkpad_acpi dbg_bluetoothemul=1 bluetooth_state=1 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf
```

reboot && block/unblock bluetooth as needed:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: Depending on the laptop version, it may be necessary to instead set the WLSW emulation option instead, using `dbg_wlswemul=1 wlsw_state=1`.  This forces a master-level wireless switch to be emulated as always being on, which could otherwise disable all wireless use in `thinkpad_acpi` driver.

Thank you very much for this answer, as it was the final piece that led me to a working solution.

Comment: works on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem before. I had the parallel installation of Windows. For working of blue-tooth, if I needed to start the blue-tooth option, I enable it with <kbd>F9</kbd> function key of Windows. Then it starts working in Linux. If you have Windows installation there just check this case.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by resetting BIOS settings. Be careful if you use EFI boot - it will erased and you will need to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> plus various keys on the first row from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Delete</kbd>. In my case, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+Insert worked.